# Could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

Tags: ros2, ros-melodic, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Description

I have been trying to install and setup [ADE](https://ade-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) using the `.aderc` file, but I get a GPU-related error. I post this here as one owner of the AutowareAuto repository in GitLab told me in the comment of [the issue](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/461) I opened.

### How to reproduce

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 (bionic) and have installed Docker 19.03 successfully (I can execute `docker run hello-world`). I have followed the Quick Start section of the [first lesson of the Autoware.Auto course](https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/autowareclass2020/-/blob/master/lectures/01_DevelopmentEnvironment/devenv.md). I am using a Laptop and have tried to do it both with and without the dedicated GPU activated, which is an NVidia GTX 1060 6GB (the integrated one is the one of the Intel i7 8750H). I would like to have this running while being able to use the GTX.

I have already searched updates for the NVidia drivers and tried to update everything in my system.

### Current Behavior

I get the following error:

```
$ cd adehome/AutowareAuto/

$ ade start
Starting ade with the following images:
ade          | 18425565a9fd | master | registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/ade:master
ade-atom     | v1.39.1      | latest | registry.gitlab.com/apexai/ade-atom:latest                                                                                                                                                            
autowareauto | c9745bf2663e | master | registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto:master                                                                                                                              
ade_registry.gitlab.com_apexai_ade-atom_latest                                                                                                                                                                                               
ade_registry.gitlab.com_autowarefoundation_autoware.auto_autowareauto_master                                                                                                                                                                 
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].                                                                                                                                            
ERROR: Command return non-zero exit code (see above): 125                                                                                                                                                                                    
  docker run -h ade --detach --name ade --env COLORFGBG --env DISPLAY --env EMAIL --env GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL --env GIT_AUTHOR_NAME --env GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL --env GIT_COMMITTER_NAME --env SSH_AUTH_SOCK --env TERM --env TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris --env USER=jmtc7 --env GROUP=jmtc7 --env USER_ID=1000 --env GROUP_ID=1000 --env VIDEO_GROUP_ID=44 -v /dev/dri:/dev/dri -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /home/jmtc7/adehome:/home/jmtc7 --env ADE_CLI_VERSION=4.1.0 --env ADE_HOME_HOSTPATH=/home/jmtc7/adehome --label ade_version=4.1.0 -v /home/jmtc7/.ssh:/home/jmtc7/.ssh -v /tmp/ssh-AsnCiCzQcdnx/agent.1739:/tmp/ssh-AsnCiCzQcdnx/agent.1739 --volumes-from ade_registry.gitlab.com_apexai_ade-atom_latest:ro --volumes-from ade_registry.gitlab.com_autowarefoundation_autoware.auto_autowareauto_master:ro --label 'ade_volumes_from=["ade_registry.gitlab.com_apexai_ade-atom_latest", "ade_registry.gitlab.com_autowarefoundation_autoware.auto_autowareauto_master"]' --gpus all --env NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all --env NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility,graphics,display --env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nvidia/lib64 --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --env ADE_IMAGE_ADE_FQN=registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/ade:master --env ADE_IMAGE_ADE_COMMIT_SHA=18425565a9fdfd2b5e9a8fd837f18f8bbd99d961 --env ADE_IMAGE_ADE_COMMIT_TAG= --env ADE_IMAGE_ADE_ATOM_FQN=registry.gitlab.com/apexai/ade-atom:latest --env ADE_IMAGE_ADE_ATOM_COMMIT_SHA=41a804c93041bf2ef4fe118676a4b6a84bdeff91 --env ADE_IMAGE_ADE_ATOM_COMMIT_TAG=v1.39.1 --env ADE_IMAGE_AUTOWAREAUTO_FQN=registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto:master --env ADE_IMAGE_AUTOWAREAUTO_COMMIT_SHA=c9745bf2663ecca9d73c20e29d8c4624b58948f5 --env ADE_IMAGE_AUTOWAREAUTO_COMMIT_TAG= --label 'ade_images=[{"fqn": "registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/ade:master", "commit_sha": "18425565a9fdfd2b5e9a8fd837f18f8bbd99d961", "commit_tag": ""}, {"fqn": "registry.gitlab.com/apexai/ade-atom:latest", "commit_sha": "41a804c93041bf2ef4fe118676a4b6a84bdeff91", "commit_tag": "v1.39.1"}, {"fqn": "registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto:master", "commit_sha": "c9745bf2663ecca9d73c20e29d8c4624b58948f5", "commit_tag": ""}]' registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/ade:master
```

Some further information about my installations and system:

```
$ which ade
/home/jmtc7/.local/bin/ade

$ nvidia-smi
Wed May 13 20:31:59 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.82       Driver Version: 440.82       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   54C    P0    25W /  N/A |    399MiB /  6078MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1127      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           203MiB |
|    0      1903      G   kwin_x11                                      60MiB |
|    0      1908      G   /usr/bin/krunner                               6MiB |
|    0      1910      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                          77MiB |
|    0      7564      G   ...quest-channel-token=2246178135911394660    42MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b7f0
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:25:46 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b7f0
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:24:19 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

### Expected behavior

The expected behavior is the one shown in this [video from the Autoware.Auto course](https://youtu.be/XTmlhvlmcf8?t=1650) in the minute 27:30, i.e. being able to start ADE without any issue to be able to enter the environment and use it, as in the minute 30:10 of the same video.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352377/could-not-select-device-driver-%22%22-with-capabilities:-%5B%5Bgpu%5D%5D./) by [jmtc7](https://answers.ros.org/users/54930/jmtc7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2020-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

## Solved. Solution:

In case someone finds himself in the same situation, I just followed the [installation for NVIDIA Docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker). It seems Docker 19.03 does not really work with GPUs by itself as I misunderstood... At least not for me. For convenience, these are the installation commands for Ubuntu/Debian:

```
# Add the package repositories
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

---

Originally posted by [jmtc7](https://answers.ros.org/users/54930/jmtc7/) with karma: 36 on 2020-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1